# Empty folder has 3.46 GB. Why?

Tags: windows, windows-10

So I've been cleaning up my desktop for the last few minutes, and I tried to delete this empty folder, but it has some 3.46GB of data in it? And I'm like wtf is going on. Any ideas of why this is happening? I restarted my computer, thinking it was just some kind of fluke, but it is still happening.

[image]

Comment: **ski32.exe** :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click the "View" ribbon and check "Hidden Items" under the "Show/hide" section.

If the contents are still not visible, disable hiding of system files:

1. Click "View" ribbon, Options
2. Select "View" tab of Folder Options.
3. Uncheck "Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)"
4. Click OK

Comment: cool thanks, guess that I had previously pushed something to github from there at one point.